# Mapbox GL JS: Coloring individual features in large GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I have a map of states with each precinct as an individual feature in Mapbox. I want to change the color of each of these precincts based on the difference between party votes.
[Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8iVJ.png) versus [what I have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk48M.png).

I tried using map.setPaintProperty, however setting one feature forces you to change every other feature that doesn't match the ID.

```
map.setPaintProperty("wisconsin", "fill-color", 
    ["match",["get", "id"],
       features[i].properties["OBJECTID"],
       color, "#ffffff"
    ]
);
```

How could I go about this or is there another method of doing so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, you want to do data-driven styling. There are basically three methods.

### Expression mapping property to color

If the attribute you want to visualise is in the data (ie, you have a `.population` property on each feature), you use an expression like:

```js
'fill-color': ['interpolate-hcl', ['linear'], ['get', 'population'], 0, 'red', 1e6, 'blue']
```

See https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/data-driven-styling/

#### Expression mapping each ID to a specific color

If your attributes are not contained within your data source, you can programmatically generate a huge expression that will look like:

```js
'fill-color': ['match', ['get', 'id'],
  1020, 'red',
  1033, 'green',
  1038, 'red',
  1049, 'white',
  // ...
```

#### Use feature-state to add the attribute at run-time

Finally, you can get better rendering performance than the previous case, albeit with some extra complexity, by calling `setFeatureState` to actually add the attribute you want at runtime.

Your style looks like this:

```js
'fill-color': ['interpolate-hcl', ['linear'], ['feature-state', 'population'], 0, 'red', 1e6, 'blue']
```

Then you iterate over every feature within the viewport to actually add that attribute:

```js
for (const district of districts) {
  map.setFeatureState({ source: 'mysource', sourceLayer: 'mysourcelayer', id: district.id }, { population: district.population});
}
```

See https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#setfeaturestate .

Comment: Okay, I've achieved what I wanted but there are some precincts so small that they are not rendered, [therefore not getting the styling needed](https://i.imgur.com/kOFojv0.png)

Comment: Btw it would be helpful if you would accept this answer with the checkmark. That means I could then use it as the duplicate target for other similar questions.

Comment: I went through and did that. And for anybody with my similar issue with incredibly small features, I just setFeatureState to any features newly rendered with getRenderedFeatures

Comment: Following the second example here, I got an error `Expected an even number of arguments.` which I solved by adding a final single argument that functions as a default.

Comment: It's good to note that the performance characteristics of feature-state are abysmal. Rendering the data takes many times longer than it would otherwise for large datasets (~2-4x longer in my testing). And the performance of the map in general is significantly degraded (choppy panning, jumpy movement, slow loading tiles...etc).

I would not recommend it if performance is a concern.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell That's not my experience - or maybe your situation is different from ones I have encountered.