# How to set individual layout properties for feature points with mapbox-gl?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have an array of feature points, and wan't to update some layout properties on each feature point, individually. How to I do this?

This is what I have so far.

```
const features = getVisibleFeatures();
// This updates all. Not what I wan't. Each feature should have different offset.
map.setLayoutProperty("ports", "text-offset", [5, 5]);
```

Each feature should have it's own `text-offset`, based on individual values. How do I achieve this?

#### Update

@steve-bennett offers some great suggestion in the comments below, but unfortunately they don't work with layout properties and the text-offset values.

It's important that a solution can work with this.

Comment: One solution would be to add each point to separate layers. Then I can do `map.queryRenderedFeatures({ layers: ["point-id"] })` and use `setLayoutProperty()`, but doesn't seem like the optimal solution.

Comment: See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63713703/mapbox-gl-js-coloring-individual-features-in-large-geojson/63715044#63715044

Comment: @SteveBennett thank you. Third option seems the best one for my use case, but looks like it maybe doesn't work with `layout: { text-offset: ...}`? I get `Error: layers.ports.layout.text-offset[0]: number expected, array found`

Comment: I would modify the features by adding the desired offset into a new "offset" and then add the features to the map and have a style with "text-offset": ["get", "offset"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching, trial and error, I figured out I could do this:

```js
map.setLayoutProperty("ports", "text-offset", {
    property: "id",
    type: "categorical",
    stops: [
      ["0", [2, 1]],
      ["1", [2, 0]],
      ["2", [0, 2]],
    ],
    default: [0, 0],
});
```

`"0"`, `"1"` and `"2"` is matched against the `properties.id` field. So I can do something like this:

```js
  map.setLayoutProperty("layout-id", "text-offset", {
    property: "id",
    type: "categorical",
    stops: nodes.map((node) => {
      const x = node.vx;
      const y = node.vy;
      return [node.id, [x, y]];
    }),
    default: [0, 0],
  });
```

Comment: Mind blown!  I've been searching for the last 6 hours how to change a Layout property of an already loaded geojson dataset, and this is the first glimmer of hope (I need to change "text-field").  A few questions:  (1) any clue whether performance is much faster for very large datasets than just reloading everything with setData() if every feature needs to be modified?  In your case, how large is "nodes"?  (2) Is there anything magical about "categorical" here?  Can one use any other operator?